# Executing makefile

Tags: c++, c, makefile

I have a makefile in which I added sources files and header files and linked them. I am 100% sure that this makefile is correct because I asked my professors and TA. However, I do not know how to execute a makefile. I have a main.c file in which I have bunch of print statements.

In my makefile I have :

```
all: main
```

I am trying to run this by following commands:

```
make clean
make main
```

However, nothing is being printed out, it just complies and thats it but I want a way to run this program, how do i do that?

Comment: You're asking how to run your program, `main`? Have you talked to those professors and TA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to *execute a makefile*; you're doing that by running make.  Make *builds* programs.  It doesn't usually *run* programs that it builds, although it can do so.

In your example above if you want to run the program after make builds it, you just use:

```
 ./main
```

to run it.  If you want to create a makefile rule that will run the program, you can add to your makefile something like:

```
run: main
        ./main
```

If you put this at the end of the makefile then you can run `make run` to build and run the program.  If you put it at the beginning of the makefile (before `all` anyway) then you can type `make` and it will build and run the program, or type `make all` or `make main` and it will just build the program without running it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `all` rule like this ...

```
make all
```

... or simply ...

```
make
```

This is assuming your makefile is named "Makefile" or "makefile".  If it is named something else, you'll need the `-f` option:

```
make -f app.mak
```

Note: I'm using "app.mak" as an example.

If you want to execute your program after making it.  You'll have to add another line, such as:

```
all: main
    ./main
```

This is assuming your executable is in the current directory and its named `main`.

Comment: I don't think you read the OP's question carefully.

Comment: @JimBalter I sure didn't.